Sympy solver returns -b+a instead of a-b
I have successfully solved a system of 19 equations and 19 variables.  The solutions will result in the correct numerical numbers but if there is a negative sign anywhere in the equation the solver will rearrange the equation so it always leads with a negative sign.
It makes no difference if I use the dict=True or not.  It makes no difference if I use eq0 = Eq(x,a-b) or eq0 = Eq(a-b,x). The resulting output always leads with a negative sign if there is a negative sign anywhere in the equation. I have defined my symbols to be positive.  Yet, no matter what I do the equations are printed with leading negative signs.  This doesn't look good if I want to publish this.

Yes, but that is a lot of work.  I would rather parse the equations an flip the signs programmatically.   I can't be the first person to have this problem. Some one must know a way but I have found nothing and I think I have tried everything but my idea about programmatically switching signs.

The solution are about the order of printing variables but they are NOT IN AN EQUATION.  Also,  there are 19 variables and the equations are the sum or differences of products and sometime divisors.  All the results should be positive as they are times, positions,  speeds, accelerations and jerks.  I use -a for the deceleration and -j for the jerk when it is negative so all the variables should be positive.  All the results should be positive.  They are positive when I assigned real values but solver always wants to make them look like negative value symbolically.
